# Comparison of 2 bitmaps with Allegro 5

Tags: allegro5

I searched a lot but I couldn't find anything about comparison of 2 bitmaps in allegro 5. There is just is_same_bitmap() in Allegro 4. I wanted to ask you if there is any easy way except comparing the pixels of bitmaps.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to compare the pixels. (Or you could compute a hash and compare them, but it's likely faster to do pixels since you can stop as soon as you find one that does not match.)

To speed things up, you should lock the bitmaps via `al_lock_bitmap_region()` and access the memory directly via the returned data structure.

Comment: Ok then I'll compare the pixels.Thank you.

Comment: I try to compare the pixels but a part of my code doesn't work.There is two bitmaps. One of them is a part of display (ALLEGRO_DISPLAY) and another is a bitmap. My code is to get the part of the display in x,y coordinate as a bitmap is below. I could only "al_create_sub_bitmap" find to get the part of display and it doesn't work. How can I get a part of display as a bitmap?

ALLEGRO_BITMAP *backbuf=al_get_backbuffer(display);
ALLEGRO_BITMAP *newbitmap =al_create_sub_bitmap(backbuf,x,y,25,25);